# Redirect user role to a specific page on login in a multisite network?

Tags: php, customization, multisite

I have been working on this for some time now. I want to redirect a specific user role to a specific page in the backend on a Multisite install.
I have been able to do this finally, but I get an error that the page was redirected incorrectly, but I can see that the URL is correct.

This is the code:

```
add_action('wp_login', function(){
    global $logging_in;
    $logging_in = true;
});

add_action('current_screen', 'primary_login_redirect');
function primary_login_redirect( $user ) {
    global $logging_in;
    $userID = get_current_user_id();
    $user_info = get_userdata($userID);
    if (($logging_in = true) && ($user_info->primary_blog)) {
        $primary_url = get_blogaddress_by_id($user_info->primary_blog) . 'wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=visitor';
        $site_id = $user_info->primary_blog;
        if (!current_user_can_for_blog($site_id, 'create_users')) {
          wp_redirect($primary_url);
          die();
        }
    }
}
```

To be able to check for capabilities I had to create the `wp_login` function which sets `$logging_in`. If I login with a user which has the `create_users` capability I go straight to Dashboard, but if I login with a user who doesn't have this capability I will be redirected to `example.com/subsite/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=visitor` (where subsite is the users main multisite). But for some reason I get an error when this redirect happens.
`The page isn’t redirecting properly` shown in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution if anyone's interested:

```
add_filter('login_redirect', function( $url, $query, $user ) {
  $user_info = get_userdata($user->ID);
  return get_blogaddress_by_id($user_info->primary_blog) .  'wp-admin/?login=1';
}, 10, 3);

add_action('current_screen', function ( $user ) {
    $userID = get_current_user_id();
    $user_info = get_userdata($userID);
    if ($_GET['login'] == 1 && $user_info->primary_blog) {
        $primary_url = get_blogaddress_by_id($user_info->primary_blog) . 'wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=visitor';
        $site_id = $user_info->primary_blog;
        if (!current_user_can_for_blog($site_id, 'create_users')) {
          wp_redirect( $primary_url );
          exit();
        }
    }
});
```